# Otimizar carregamento de select PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Olá, eu tenho um form onde eu preciso carregar dois selects que recebem do banco aproximadamente 13.000 registros cada. Inicialmente eu criei uma função que carregava os registros e imprimia  o código HTML da opção e usava ela uma vez em cada select. Como a performance não foi satisfatória dividi a função em duas para que a consulta fosse feita apenas uma vez mas mesmo assim quando chega na parte que deve renderizar o select há uma demora de aproximadamente 8s pra cada e isso no localhost, no server deve é maior ainda. Gostaria que alguém me orientasse em como otimizar o carregamento dessa página. Desde já agradeço. Seguem os códigos:

Coloquei o form no pastebin para melhor visualização e removi do formulário a parte posterior ao aos selects mencionados: [cadastra_jogo.php](http://pastebin.com/0GT5xJvT)

Funções:

```
//Lista todos os times
function lista_times()
{
    $link = conectar();

    $query = "SELECT tb_time.id as id_time, tb_time.nome_time, tb_campeonato.nome_camp
              FROM tb_campeonato, tb_time
              WHERE tb_time.tb_campeonato_id = tb_campeonato.id";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(print_r(mysqli_error()));

    //return $result;

    $header_atual="";

    $registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    return $registro;

}

//Preenche o select com todos os times
function preenche_time_combo($registro)
{
    while ($registro) {
        if($registro['nome_camp'] != $header_atual){
            if($header_atual != ""){
                echo "</optgroup>";
            }

            echo "<optgroup label='".$registro['nome_camp']."'>";
            $header_atual = $registro['nome_camp'];
        }

        echo "<option value='" . $registro['id_time'] . "'>" . $registro['nome_time'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</optgroup>";
}
```

Comment: Você quer exibir no HTML os 13 mil registros?

Comment: É uma lista de todos os times do mundo. Eu pensei em carregar os times baseado no campeonato mas vai ter ocasiões que o campeonato ao qual o time pertence tem que ser desconsiderado. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tem q carregar o minimo possível e ir buscando com ajax conforme necessário, pelo menos essa seria a abordagem padrão que eu vejo em um caso desses, mas isso pq tb não sei nada da sua tela.

Comment: Por mim pode existir dois problemas. A query está demorando muito para ser executada, então use o `cache`, ponha no my.cnf o valor `query_cache_type = 2` e use `SELECT SQL_CACHE ...`. O outro problema é o loop estar demorando muito, o que não não tenho certeza, uma solução, que não sei quão eficiente, é usar `echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all(...))` e então o cliente (por AJAX) montar a tabela. O `mysqli_fetch_all` nesse situação pode comer mais RAM que o Chrome, esteja preparado. :P

Comment: @Inkeliz eu nunca vi falar dessa solução. Poderia me dar um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: Infelizmente não daria para dar um exemplo nos comentários, adicionei como resposta e acrescentei a solução de definir um LIMIT.

Comment: Se te serve, use datatables jQuery server-side processing... para a quantidade de registros cairá bem, e a implementação é fácil e a curva de aprendizado é ótima https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 0):

> **Não sei quão eficiente isso é!**

Uma maneira seria usar o `cache` em conjunto com o `mysqli_fetch_all`.

O PHP seria assim:

```
$limite = filter_var($_GET['limit'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && $_GET['limit'] !== 0 ? $limite : 2147483647;

$query = "SELECT SQL_CACHE tb_time.id as id_time, tb_time.nome_time, tb_campeonato.nome_camp
              FROM tb_campeonato, tb_time
              WHERE tb_time.tb_campeonato_id = tb_campeonato.id
              LIMIT ".$limite;

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result));
```

Dessa forma o `mysqli_fetch_all` irá fazer um loop (não explicito) de todos os dados e então o `json_encode` irá entregar os dados como estão, assim quem deverá tratar os dados é o cliente.

O JQuery seria:

```
$.getJSON('seu_arquivo_do_php.php?limit=0',    
    function(json){

        $.each(json, function(indice, data){

             $('select').append(new Option(data[1], data[0]));

         });

    }   
);
```

O JQuery por sua vez poderá apenas adicionar o `option` ao `select`. Também poderá limitar a quantidade a ser exibida. Você poderá então colocar uma opção para carregar mais do que X, por exemplo.

> Pode ocorrer, no servidor, alto uso de memoria RAM!

**Otimização do MYSQL (acredito que mais eficaz)!**

Use CACHE:

Altere o `my.cnf`:

```
query_cache_type = 2
```

Execute como demonstrado:

```
SELECT SQL_CACHE ...
```

Use INDEX:

Execute:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_time
ADD INDEX tb_campeonato_id        
(tb_campeonato_id);

ALTER TABLE tb_campeonato
ADD INDEX id    
(id);
```