# Função PHP só funciona na primeira chamada

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Eu estou chamando a mesma função php, na qual eu passo como parâmetro um result do banco de dados, duas vezes no script porém ela só funciona na primeira chamada.

Percebi que se eu chamar a função que retorna o resultado da query e passar para outra varíavel que por sua vez é passada como parâmetro para a função que antes não funcionava, ela passa à funcionar.

Sei que estou deixando passar algum ponto do funcionamento do php, gostaria de uma mãozinha nessa.

Lembrando que estou chamando a mesma função por que preciso de um select exatamente igual ao anterior, alguém sugere alguma maneira mais otimizada de fazer isso? Pois a função carrega aproximadamente 13.000 registros do banco o que faz a página demorar pra carregar.

```
<!--TIMES-->
<div class="page-header">
    <h4>Times</h4>
        <hr>
</div>
<?php
    $registro = lista_times();
    //$registro2 = lista_times();
?>
<div style="padding: 20px; align-content: center" class="row" id="times-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="time_casa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Casa</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?php //var_dump($registro); ?>
                <select style="width: 300px" class="form-control chosen-select" id="time_casa" name="time_casa" data-error="Por favor, selecione o time de casa." required>
                    <?php echo preenche_time_combo($registro); ?>
                </select>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php //var_dump($registro); ?>
        <label for="time_fora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fora</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select style="width: 300px" class="form-control chosen-select" id="time_fora" name="time_fora" data-error="Por favor, selecione o time de fora." required>
                <?php echo preenche_time_combo($registro); ?>
            </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--TIMES-->
```

`lista_times()` executa a query e retorna o resultado e `preenche_time_combo()` retorna uma string com o código html com uma option pra cada elemento recuperado do banco.

```
//Lista todos os jogos ativos
function lista_times()
{
    $link = conectar();
    $query = "SELECT tb_time.id as id_time, tb_time.nome_time, tb_campeonato.nome_camp
              FROM tb_campeonato, tb_time
              WHERE tb_time.tb_campeonato_id = tb_campeonato.id";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(print_r(mysqli_error()));

    return $result;

}

function preenche_time_combo($result)
{
    $header_atual="";

    $html="";

    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($registro['nome_camp'] != $header_atual){
            if($header_atual != ""){
                $html .= "</optgroup>";
            }

            $html .= "<optgroup label='".$registro['nome_camp']."'>";
            $header_atual = $registro['nome_camp'];
        }

        $html .= "<option value='" . $registro['id_time'] . "'>" . $registro['nome_time'] . "</option>";
    }

    $html .= "</optgroup>";

    return $html;

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Amigo 2 combos com 13 mil registros vai garrar, você já tentou utilizar um ajax para montar um autocomplete? Quer algumas sugestões de plugin?

Comment: @Euler01, eu adoraria alguma sugestão. Dei uma pesquisada em como otimizar isso mas não consegui uma solução satisfatória. Agradeço se o amigo puder me ajudar, abraço!

Comment: O `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, segundo a documentação, "retorna uma matriz associativa que corresponde a linha obtida e move o ponteiro interno dos dados adiante." Ou seja, você precisaria reiniciar o ponteiro para o primeiro registro para percorrer o resultado novamente (com `mysqli_data_seek`). Não tenho certeza se é uma boa alternativa.

Comment: vc vai mesmo continuar com essa ideia dos 13 mil registros numa só página? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146765/otimizar-carregamento-de-select-phpmysql  Agora, além dos 13 mì são 26 mil.. e tudo dentro de select option...

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeRamalho, de uma olhada no https://select2.github.io e procure por "Loading remote data". Voce vai precisar importar o css do Bootstrap também. Ou então o bom e velho http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em `preenche_time_combo()` cada chamada de `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` está altera/esvazia a váriavel `$registro` fora da função (alteração por referência), por isso a segunda chamada não funciona.

A forma mais simples de solucionar isso é armazenar as options já geradas em uma variável e depois imprimir ela dentro dos `<select>`

Mude a chamade:

```
<?php
   $registro = lista_times();
```

Para:

```
<?php
   $options = preenche_time_combo(lista_times());
```

E por último (removi o style para simplificar o exemplo):

```
<select>
   <?php echo $options;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho! Obrigado pela dica, cara! Agora só preciso achar um maneira de otimizar o carregamento. O que vocês acham do desempenho? Vou deixar um vídeo pra vocês darem uma olhada. Isso deve piorar bastante quando estiver hospedado em um servidor e tiver tráfego, certo?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoB7-U7askQ

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho pq vcprecisa carregar tanto registros do banco? se resolveu pode marcar a resposta como aceita como sinal verde, veja em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Comment: Esses registros são a lista de todos os times de futebol do mundo. O usuário deverá ser capaz de escolher dois times de uma partida  entre qualquer time do mundo. Pensei em limitar à consulta aos times pertencentes ao campeonato "x"  selecionado no primeiro select mas há casos em que eu não posso limitar ao campeonato.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho e separar por país não seria melhor?

Comment: Também pensei mas alguns registros que estão na tabela tb_pais não são países na verdade, porém dá pra tratar como tal. Eu na verdade não sabia o quanto de recurso o carregamento desses registros consumiria dado que esse é o meu primeiro sistema web e que à primeira vista, como no vídeo, não demorou tanto pra carregar. Mas agradeço por todas as dicas. Só uma pergunta: O jquery iria pegar os registros do banco e fazer um append no HTML, certo? Fora que a página ia carregar primeiro e os registros depois teria ganho de desempenho além da estética da página que não mostraria os elementos mais?